# Is it possible to reprocess a fragment shader before it is drawn to the screen?

Tags: opengl

Is there a way to make the fragment shader pass through another fragment shader before it is drawn? As in the following example:

Consider that I want to draw a scene but only inside a shape, I can check in the shader
if the TexCoords of the fragment are inside the shape I want.

Pass 1: Bind post processing shader

Pass 2: Draw se scene

Pass 3: Bind default or disable post processing shader

Drawing without post processing shader

[image: Drawing without post processing shader]

Drawing with post processing shader

[image: Drawing with post processing shader]

I'm aware of the **framebuffer**, and it works, but it goes through a process of rendering the whole screen, and that can cost me performance in the future, especially considering that this post processing shader will be turned on, off and reset several times during the rendering of a frame

Comment: you can put the two things you want to do into one shader

Comment: It will be a problem when drawing different things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL does not recognize the idea of chaining shader stages in the manner you suggest. During any particular rendering operation, there is exactly one fragment shader active. Period.

Of course, OpenGL also *does not care* where your shader strings come from. It doesn't care if there's a single file on a disk with that text in it or not. All it cares about is that you pass text corresponding to valid GLSL to `glShaderSource`.

So if you like, you can *manufacture* a single shader from multiple conceptual "shaders". This can be as simple as just concatenating a bunch of file strings together (which `glShaderSource` [can do for you, since it takes multiple strings](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Compilation#Shader_object_compilation)), or it can be a complex operation where you recognize certain variables as interface variables and carefully synthesize a `main` function from these disparate pieces.

How you go about doing that is ultimately up to you.

Alternatively, you can take an "ubershader" approach. That is, put all of the possible post-processing stuff in one shader, and use uniform variables to tell whether or not a particular post-processing step is currently active.

Answer (score 0):

Write a shader that does both things: calculates the colour, *and* discards the fragment if it's outside a certain shape. Render the scene with that shader.

Perhaps if you want to avoid wasting time processing pixels outside the shape, you can set the "scissor rectangle" to the bounding box of your shape, so OpenGL won't even run the shader for pixels outside that box.

Comment: Scissor does not support rectangle with rounded corners.
What if I want a different effect? how to make the drawn pixels black and white, I would have to rewrite all my shaders again.

Comment: @RobsonCosta then you write a shader that makes black and white pixels but only when the pixels are inside the shape... right?

Comment: @RobsonCosta You haven't really presented your complete problem but it does sound as if you might want to look into using a stencil buffer for the masking.

Comment: @G.M. sounds like you have another answer to add